# mouseenter is not firing when mousedown is fired in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have two lists in div tag. I am trying to Drag & Drop type functionality in my code. It is working with Chrome but not working in IE

When a mouse is entered on div I am recording its id "Selected" or "Removed" in "listSelected" variable and in MouseUp event I am checking on which div mouse button is released using variable "listSelected". MouseDown event is implemented to know starting div tag & user expecting drag operation.

But problem is after MouseDrag event is fired, MouseEnter event is not firing in IE. It is working in Chrome. When I release the button then MouseEnter or MouseOver events are firing not firing instantly while dragging.

It will helpful if anyone know how to handle this in IE. Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div id="lstRmv" style="float: left; background-color:antiquewhite" onclick="return MouseClick();" onmousedown="return MouseDown(event,'Removed');" onmouseenter="return MouseEnter('Removed');" onmouseout="return MouseLeave(event, 'Removed');">
    <h5>Removed Transactions</h5>
    <asp:ListBox ID="lst_AllTrn" class="defaultcursor" runat="server" Rows="15" Width="225px" Height="200px" onclick="return MouseClick();" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
</div>
<div id="lstSel" style="float: left" class="drop"  onmousedown="return MouseDown(event,'Selected');" onmouseenter="return MouseEnter('Selected');" onmouseout="return MouseLeave(event, 'Selected');">
    <h5>Selected Transactions</h5>
    <asp:ListBox ID="lst_SelectedTrn" class="defaultcursor" runat="server" Rows="15" Width="225px" Height="200px" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
function MouseLeave(e, id) {
    if (listSelected == id)
            listSelected = "";
}

function MouseEnter(id) {
    listSelected = id;
}

function MouseDown(e, id) {
    listDrag = id;
        $('.defaultcursor').css('cursor', 'move');
        dragging = true;
}

function MouseUp(e) {
    if (dragging) {
            if (listDrag == 'Removed' && listSelected == "Selected")
                    alert("Transaction Selected");
                else if (listDrag == 'Selected' && listSelected == "Removed")
                    alert("Transaction Removed");
            }
            dragging = false;
            $('.defaultcursor').css('cursor', 'default');
}
```

Comment: have you checked is there any javascript error?

Comment: @Sanjay I checked there is no javascript error. It is working with chrome. events are firing without MouseDown event is progress